# How can i store data in Mobile Data of Bluemix

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I have ran the android version of bluelist tutorial in bluemix.

This app saves data as key-value. For example firstname:.

What if i want to store last name too? Can i create a second "column" or should i make my "person" object a json string and store it?

Comment: Find documentation / tutorial in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the tutorial here (http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/android).  You can store a Java object in the mobile data service.  Behind the scenes it is storing JSON for you.  If you want you can obviously store straight JSON but it was abstracted a bit so it models more closley how Java dev's use OO to store and access data.

Scroll down to the data operations bit (http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/android#data-operations), you can store and access data normally as you would through a class in Java.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done eventually is that i stored a json string like

```
{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Foo"}
```

In the bluelist application i maintain 2 Lists, one for the whole object and one for the fistsnames only.

By this way i see only the firstname but i can store more than one properties.

(of course as there is one editbox i can set and edit only one property. The second property is a static string - eg it is always John - but i just wanted to test the functionality of the key-value database so it is ok for me.)

This is the accepted answer so far. If there is any other way please answer with an example as i am not too much familiar with this kind of database.

Answer (score -1):

if its a web application,you can use similar logic like below:

```
  var newUser = {
        'username': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
        'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
        'fullname': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(),
        'age': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserAge').val(),
        'location': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocation').val(),
        'gender': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserGender').val()
    }
    // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newUser,
        url: '/users/adduser',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response )
```

You can follow below link for more details on how to add new column and doing insert/update/delete operation on this:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/